# CSS Centering isnt possible

Tags: html, css, centering

My Problem is that I cant get the menu in my Footer centered (http://prntscr.com/te8bzk) when I'm in the portrait mode (I'm working with media queries). `position: absolute; + right: 50%;` isn't working. But maybe I overlooked something because I'm still a beginner in HTML and CSS. Js fiddle link is https://jsfiddle.net/Cxtz11/mrz2L1dt/1/

```css
.main-footer {
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-width: thick;
  background;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: inherit;
}

.footer-nav {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 50%;
}

.footer-nav li {
  float: left;
}

.footer-nav li+li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.Copyright {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin-top: 80px;
  color: #fff;
}

.Social {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer" class="main-footer clearfix">
  <p class="Copyright clearfix">
    S &copy; 2020
  </p>
  <h1 class="Social clearfix">
    <a href="https://instagram.com"> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> </a>
  </h1>
  <ul class="footer-nav clearfix">
    <li><a href="/Impressum/Impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Datenschutz/Datenschutz.html">Datenschutz</a></li>
    <li><a href="/AGB/AGB.html">AGB</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

(You may have to adjust the "display window" in JSfiddle to portrait because I'm working with media queries and there are two versions of my site.

Comment: I would consider playing with the display flex properties for all positioning. This will end up getting you closer to what you want on all displays.

Comment: Also your JS-fiddle link does not include the image you want centered. I'm getting only a broken image link.

Comment: I dont want the Image centered but the Menu in the footer.
The Image is working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, **your styling convention is not so good here and I strongly suggest rewriting your styles entirely for sake of maintainable code**. But regards to your current style there is a simple fix that should help to make your menu center as expected.

So you have to make your `footer-nav` class like this:

```css
.footer-nav {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

You can't directly use `display: flex;` here alone because your `ul` element is extremely out of position, so you need to make sure to put your element inside your current box with `right: 0` and `left: 0` properties. Then you can use `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` as usual. Also due to the default `ul` element default padding for starting items, you need to set your padding to 0 as well.

Then your final code should be something like this:

```css
.main-footer {
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-width: thick;
  background;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: inherit;
}

.footer-nav {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer-nav li {
  float: left;
}

.footer-nav li+li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.Copyright {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin-top: 80px;
  color: #fff;
}

.Social {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<footer id="footer" class="main-footer clearfix">
  <p class="Copyright clearfix">
    S &copy; 2020
  </p>
  <h1 class="Social clearfix">
    <a href="https://instagram.com"> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> </a>
  </h1>
  <ul class="footer-nav clearfix">
    <li><a href="/Impressum/Impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Datenschutz/Datenschutz.html">Datenschutz</a></li>
    <li><a href="/AGB/AGB.html">AGB</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

---

If in any case, you are looking for a slight refactor you can use the below version.

```css
.main-footer {
  position: relative;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-width: thick;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Social {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.Social .fab {
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-nav {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer-nav li+li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.Copyright {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<footer id="footer" class="main-footer clearfix">
  <div class="Social clearfix">
    <a href="https://instagram.com"> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="footer-nav">
    <li><a href="/Impressum/Impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Datenschutz/Datenschutz.html">Datenschutz</a></li>
    <li><a href="/AGB/AGB.html">AGB</a></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="Copyright clearfix">
    S &copy; 2020
  </p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `right: 50%` uses the right side of the image/footer nav to base the position (`left: 50%` uses the left edge of the element) - so the right side of your `.Social` and `.footer-nav` element is in the middle.

Without changing your code, you can add `transform: translate(50%,0)` to the `.Social` and `.footer-nav` elements. `transform` uses the `width` of the elements to determine where it moves from.

So, `transform: translate(50%,0)` is saying: move the element 50% to the left using the width of the element.

```css
.main-footer {
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-width: thick;
  background;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: inherit;
}

.footer-nav {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 0);
}

.footer-nav li {
  float: left;
}

.footer-nav li+li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.Copyright {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin-top: 80px;
  color: #fff;
}

.Social {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translate(50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer" class="main-footer clearfix">
  <p class="Copyright clearfix">
    S &copy; 2020
  </p>
  <h1 class="Social clearfix">
    <a href="https://instagram.com"> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> </a>
  </h1>
  <ul class="footer-nav clearfix">
    <li><a href="/Impressum/Impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Datenschutz/Datenschutz.html">Datenschutz</a></li>
    <li><a href="/AGB/AGB.html">AGB</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```